# My RSpec test keeps returning a NoMethodError for one of my ActiveRecord Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a ***Users*** and **Listings** table whose schema is below:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "name"
  end

  create_table "listings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "listing_type"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.integer  "neighborhood_id"
    t.integer  "host_id"
    t.string   "host"
  end
```

And my **models for Listing and User** are below:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :neighborhood
  belongs_to :hosts, :class_name => "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listings, :foreign_key => 'host_id'
end
```

But when I run my RSpec tests, I receive the following NoMethodError:

```
  1) Listing belongs to a host
     Failure/Error: expect(listing.host.name).to eq("Amanda")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `name' for "#<User:0x007fc885001838>":String
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `host` String column in `listings` table.
So `listing.host` returns a String from that column. Then you call `name` on it.
Of course there is no such method.

I think you have wrong association. Try

```
belongs_to :host, :class_name => "User"
```

not `hosts`.

And remove `t.string "host"` from `listings` table.

Comment: Thanks! That was it!